# Facebook Shimmer library with Paging 3 library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3, shimmer

In my app I load data from API which is using paginating so I have to use paging 3 library
and I use facebook shimmer library to show shimmer effect when items are being loaded
but the problem is always shimmer effect is shown even when items are completely loaded

**ArticlePagingAdapter.kt**

```
class ArticlePagingAdapter(private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
    PagingDataAdapter<Article, ArticlePagingAdapter.ViewHolder>(ArticleDiffUtil()) {
    private val TAG = ArticlePagingAdapter::class.simpleName
    private lateinit var context: Context
    var showShimmer: Boolean = true

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        lateinit var item: Article
        val shimmerLayout: ShimmerFrameLayout = itemView.shimmer_layout
        val articleImageView: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_image_view)
        val articleTitleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_title_text_view)
        val articleEstimatedTextView: TextView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_estimated_read_time_text_view)
        val clockImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clock_icon)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (showShimmer) {
            holder.shimmerLayout.startShimmer()
        } else {

            holder.shimmerLayout.stopShimmer()
            holder.shimmerLayout.setShimmer(null)
            holder.articleImageView.background = null
            holder.clockImageView.background = null
            holder.articleEstimatedTextView.background = null
            holder.articleTitleTextView.background = null

            val item = getItem(position)
            if (item != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "position $position, isNull != null ")
                holder.item = item
                holder.articleTitleTextView.text = item.title
                holder.articleEstimatedTextView.text = (item.estimatedReadingTime.toString()

                val requestOptions = RequestOptions().transform(
                    CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(
                        context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.item_article_image_view_radius)
                            .toInt()
                    )
                )
                    Glide.with(context).load(item.imageUrl!!.toUri())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_article_placeholder).apply(requestOptions)
                        .into(holder.articleImageView)
                holder.clockImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clock)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "position $position, isNull= null ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ArticleFragmnet.kt**

```
class LatestArticlesFragment : Fragment(), ArticlePagingAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    val TAG = LatestArticlesFragment::class.simpleName
    lateinit var binding: FragmentLatestArticlesBinding
    

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

    // some unrelated code 
   
        val adapter = ArticlePagingAdapter(this)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.getArticles().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                adapter.submitData(data)
                Log.d(TAG,"data ${data.toString()}")
                adapter.showShimmer = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ArticleFragmentViewModel.kt**

```
class LatestArticlesFragmentViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val repository: ArticleRepository, ...) : ViewModel() {

    fun getArticles(): LiveData<PagingData<Article>> {
        currentArticles = repository.getArticlesStream().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        return currentArticles?.asLiveData()!!
    }
}
```

**item_article.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/card_view_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp">

    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/very_small_padding">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_image_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/article_title_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_title_text_view"
                style="@style/Widget.MyWidget.TextView.VerySmall.Bold"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/very_small_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/very_small_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="?attr/textColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clock_icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/article_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/article_image_view"
                tools:text="This is a dummy title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_estimated_read_time_text_view"
                style="@style/Widget.MyWidget.TextView.VerySmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/very_small_margin"
                android:background="@color/shimmer_background"
                android:textColor="?attr/textColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/article_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/article_title_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/clock_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/article_title_text_view"
                tools:text="5 min" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/clock_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@color/shimmer_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/article_estimated_read_time_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/article_estimated_read_time_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/article_title_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/article_estimated_read_time_text_view"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**fragment_article_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/articleBackground">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_text_view"
            style="@style/Widget.MyWidget.TextView.Large.Bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:text="@string/articles"
            android:textColor="?attr/textColor"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line_separator"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/article_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/right_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/article_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/article_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/article_text_view"
            tools:itemCount="8"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_article" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="?attr/listFadeBackground"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recycler_view" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.03" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you also add your fragments layout file here?

Comment: @VishistVarugeese added fragment layout file

Comment: Try to put `adapter.showShimmer = false` before calling `submitData(data)`.